# Request.HTML mootools 1.2.5 load external file javascript

Tags: mootools

I have ajax tabs that load external files 
see demo here please bottom of the page 
http://www.php-help.ro/examples/mootools_fancy_tabs/
they work perfect but my external file has additional 1 javascript file and inline javascript 
example :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEvent('load', function(){
       /*something here*/ 
       });
      </script>
```

on tab load any request to script tag is removed , I dont see anywhere in the file itself that

evalScripts:  is set to false , I also added it in right after

url:this.tabs[key].get('href'),

I setup the file on Jsfidle but seems like ajax can load only internal files 
http://jsfiddle.net/PUsBg/16/

if anyone could help me out just to be able to load my own script within the ajax tab.

Thank you!

Comment: it is not clear what you are trying to do. there is a same origin policy applicable to all ajax requests - means it can only load resources from the same domain and under the same protocol as the host page. if you need to bring in stuff from elsewhere, you should look at using JSONP, though this won't return anything but JSON data that you have to interpolate and insert into the open tab manually. there are other ways around it, namely: write a local proxy that gets the remote content, or read on www.enable-cors.org

Comment: the issue is here, var tabContent = new Request.HTML({
                url:this.tabs[key].get('href'),
                onSuccess: function(tree, elems, html){  the request returns only html no js from source site , i need it to return everything including the js scripts

Comment: the mootools request class has one way of dealing with this. first, `evalScripts: true` will eval/run the code in script tags that you send. however, there won't be any window events fired as the dom is ready at runtime so don't base your code around load callbacks. look at https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/1.2.5/Source/Request/Request.HTML.js#L68 also, `this.response.javascript` ought to contain the scripts as an array (I think).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the result of parsing the request, with the javascript being thrown out in the process. If you include javascript within a CDATA-section, it should not be parsed and still be included:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
        window.addEvent('load', function(){
            /*something here*/ 
        });
    /* ]]> */
</script>
```